# Finding Max Value in Col of a Frequency Table in R Language

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have created a frequency table (`table(thing1, thing2)`) and I am trying to find a maximum value for one of the columns. Here is my code:

```
apmData$bin <- as.factor(apmData$bin)
apmBinTable <-table(apmData$bin, apmData$duration1) 
prop.table(apmBinTable, 1)
```

This is a fraction of my data (bad to good obvi):

```
bin id    bad      good                
416082 0.010033445 0.989966555
416084 0.017421603 0.982578397
416085 0.023041475 0.976958525
416086 0.019943020 0.980056980
416087 0.005813953 0.994186047
416093 0.017667845 0.982332155
416095 0.015822785 0.984177215
```

Here is my problem. I don't see a way to get the max value for the column "bad". Technically "bad" and "good" aren't columns because apmBinTable isn't a data.frame. Any suggestions?

Comment: max(apmData$bad ?)

Answer (score 0):

I'd redo the whole thing in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

apmData %>%
  group_by(bin) %>%
  summarise(bad = sum(duration1 == 'bad')/n()*100,
            good = sum(duration1 == 'good')/n()*100) %>%
  arrange(desc(bad))
```

The awkwardness of using tables was one of the main reasons I switched to `dplyr`!